# Cosmos DB RU Usage by collection name

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to find what's causing the higher RU usage on the Cosmos DB. I enabled the Log Analytics on the Doc DB and ran the below Kusto query to get the RU consumption by Collection Name.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(24hr)
| where Category == "DataPlaneRequests"
| summarize ConsumedRUsPer15Minute = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)) by collectionName_s, _ResourceId, bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
| project TimeGenerated , ConsumedRUsPer15Minute , collectionName_s, _ResourceId
| render timechart
```

We have only one collection on the DocDb Account (prd-entities) which is represents Red line in the Chart. I am not able to figure out what the Blue line represents.
Is there a way to get more details about the empty collection name RU usage (i.e., Blue line)

[image: RU Consumption By Collection Name]

Comment: How's it going? Did you find more details on those requests? You can share your further issue here if exists : )

Comment: "requestResourceId_s" is the field I was missing. It gave me more insight, Thank you! I still see values like "AsbTAkTegQA=" in requestResourceId_s that are having very high usage.

Comment: It's out of my knowledge, maybe it comes from mistaken code? How about picking some of those strange rows and add into your question, so that someone who saw similar records may help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think there's no `empty collection` costs RU actually.

Per my testing in my side, I found that when I execute your kusto query I can also get the 'empty collection', but when I watch the line details, I found all these rows are existing in my operation. What I mean here is that we shouldn't sum by `collectionName_s` especially you only have one collection in total, you may try to use `requestResourceId_s` instead.

[image]

When using `requestResourceId_s`, there're still some rows has no id, but they cost 0.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(24hr)
| where Category == "DataPlaneRequests"
| summarize ConsumedRUsPer15Minute = sum(todouble(requestCharge_s)) by requestResourceId_s, bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
| project TimeGenerated , ConsumedRUsPer15Minute , requestResourceId_s
| render timechart
```

[image]

Actually, you can check the requestCharge_s are coming from which operation, just watch details in `Results`, but not in `Chart`, and order by the `collectionName_s`, then you'll see those requests creating from the 'empty collection', judge if these requests existing in your collection.

[image]